# How to highlight a line in the Visual Studio Code editor sidebar (via Extension)?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am trying to highlight the **sidebar** for Visual Studio Code Editor via a custom extension.

The documentation has information only about highlighting a **text** in a line. Here is how the desired result should look like (highlighting changed lines for git):

[image: Visual Studio Code Git Hightlighting]

Is it possible to highlight a line in the sidebar via extension API?

Comment: If the git extension can do it you should be able as well. Study their extension code for details.

Comment: @Pavel: have you figured it out?